# Set-Mailbox Exchange Online cmdlet doesn't recognize -CustomAttribute1 parameter

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm creating a script that will update a user's Exchange Mailbox CustomAttribute1 via PowerShell. I connected to our O365 server and ran it. The documentation specifically says this attribute exists however it's not being recognized:

[image]

And this is very strange because on the documentation the parameter is clearly there:

[image]

Any idea why this is happening? We use a 100% cloud environment meaning I'm connected to an Exchange Online shell.

Comment: We've seen similar in the past (being able to call a command with a parameter but the command appears unable to 'see' it'). Ultimately this was due to RBAC. Some reading: https://practical365.com/exchange-online/how-to-report-on-exchange-rbac-assignments/

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Robin! The parameter existed but the account I connected to Exchange Online didn't have enough permissions. After logging in with another account that has Global Admin it worked like a charm.